# Syntax Error Python 3.3.3 No Reason Given

Tags: python, syntax

my program keeps throwing up a syntax error with no reason given with this code and I cannot figure out why for the life of me. I've deduced that the error-causing lines are the ones I have hashed-out

```
#char = ord(message[i])-96
#key = ord(keyword[i])-96
```

They are in lines 15 and 16 of the code. Please help me!!!

```
option = input("Do you want to encrypt or decrypt? (E/D): ")
keyword = input("Enter your keyword: ")
message = input("Enter your message: ")
while len(keyword)<len(message):
    keyword=keyword+keyword
keyword=keyword[:len(message)]
newMessage = ""
for i in range(len(message)):
    char = ord(message[i])
    key = ord(keyword[i])
    if char==32:
        newMessage = newMessage+" "
    elif char<97 or char>122:
        message = input("Enter your message: ")
    #char = ord(message[i])-96
    #key = ord(keyword[i])-96 
    elif option == "E":
        if char+key>26:
            newMessage = newMessage+chr(char+key-26)
        else:
            newMessage = newMessage+chr(char+key)
    else:
        if char-key<1:
            newMessage = newMessage+chr(char-key+26)
        else:
            newMessage = newMessage+chr(char-key)
print(newMessage)
```

Comment: You have a dangling `elif:`; you should have written `if option == 'E'`

Comment: Have you indented it the way it is displayed in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ending your `if` and subsequent `elif` with those two lines. As a result, `elif option == "E":` makes no sense as there is no preceding `if` statement before it. You either have to indent:

```
elif char<97 or char>122:
        message = input("Enter your message: ")
        char = ord(message[i])-96
        key = ord(keyword[i])-96
```

Or begin a new `if` statement with your subsequent `elif`:

```
if option == "E":
    if char+key>26:
        newMessage = newMessage+chr(char+key-26)
    else:
        newMessage = newMessage+chr(char+key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not indented (put 4 space before) the two lines. As your are in a `if` statement you have to put them.